# Using html within the addSuccess() method

Tags: magento

I have to insert an anchor tag within a success message. Magento strips out the html when the message is displayed.

Is there a workaround for this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag Mage_Core_Block_Messages::$_escapeMessageFlag defines if to use htmlEscape() method with the message text, so you can set up your rule for the selected path.

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(false);
```